# Comparing two time_t variables generates a compiler warning

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I know it must be a simple warning but am unable to resolve it.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define FILE_PATH "/sdcard/ex_file.txt"
static time_t time_now;

int main()
{
    struct stat f_stat;
    stat(FILE_PATH, &file_stat);
    time_now = time(&time_now);
    if (file_stat.st_mtime > time_now)
        unlink(FILE_PATH)
}
```

In this simple program I get a warning at `if (file_stat.st_mtime > time_now))`. I am compiling source code in Android environment.

What could be the problem? Here both are `time_t` variables.

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

Comment: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/bionic/libc/include/sys/stat.h

Comment: you do know that FILE is a define in stdio.h ? use another name. the filename should have quotation marks around it to be valid. "/sdcard/ex_file.txt"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**: this will vary depending on platform, but `struct stat` is not (always) defined with `time_t`, so you'll run into this warning on any platform where `time_t` and `unsigned long` are not the same thing.

`time_t` in linux is just a typedef for `__kernel_time_t`, which is usually a typedef for something else anyway, but this can vary depending on platform.

Now, `struct stat` does is not *always* defined with `time_t`, for example, on this Ubuntu 12.04 server (x64) I just checked, the actual `stat.h` header has this in it's definition:

```
struct stat {
    /** .............. **/
    unsigned long   st_atime;
    unsigned long   st_atime_nsec;
    unsigned long   st_mtime;
    unsigned long   st_mtime_nsec;
    unsigned long   st_ctime;
    unsigned long   st_ctime_nsec;
};
```

As you can see, it's clearly defined as `unsigned long`, not `time_t`.  Now, this server also happens to have `time_t` defined to `__kernel_time_t`, which is defined as:

```
typedef __kernel_long_t       __kernel_time_t;
```

So, when I try to compile your code (after cleaning up your syntax issues and replacing `FILE` with a real file), everything compiles fine and there is no warning, because in this case `time_t` and `unsigned long` are the same thing.

#### EDIT

Thanks to a comment by shree.pat18, you can see how android's stat.h is using `unsigned long`:
http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/bionic/libc/include/sys/stat.h

And how types.h defines "time_t" as "__kernel_time_t"
http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/bionic/libc/include/sys/types.h

And where "__kernel_time_t" is defined as "long" (and *not* "unsigned long", which is why you're getting the warning):
http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/kernel/include/asm-x86/posix_types_64.h

Comment: You should clarify that this is a **bug** in Android.

Comment: @R. I'm not sure it's a bug just in Android; it is possible other platforms have this typedef'd wrong as well

Comment: If so then it's a bug in those platforms too.

Comment: note: `time_t` is defined by Standard C; it must be an integral type or a floating point type. There's no constraint on which of these types it is.